# What is the most efficient method to fill pandas dataframe's column based on values in previous rows?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to fill the ID column- if ID is empty fill the value of the previous row, if it is not empty, keep the current ID value.
I used a for loop to do it, however this method is very slow.
my dataframe can contain 500,000 rows and I need a method which is much more efficient.
do you have any idea?

this is the output I expect:

[image]

this is the script I use now, which is very slow:

```
data.sort_values(['Tool','Date'], inplace= True)
for index in np.arange(len(data)):
    print(index)
    if data.iloc[index]['ID']=='':
        data.iloc[index, data.columns.get_loc('ID')] = data.iloc[index-1]['ID']
del index
```